# Override / cancel iPad application switch gesture

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

I want to track four finger touches in my application, but they are cancelled as the iPad uses the four finger swipe to switch applications. 
Is there a way to cancel / override this gesture?

Comment: ... programatically, I know about the Settings switch.

Comment: Why do do you think you should be able to override your users' desire to switch applications?

Comment: This broke one of my apps. I had a "desktop" in which you could move images around as many as 11 at once (because iOS supports 11 "fingers" (yes you have to use your nose or anything else for the last one). However iOS 5.0 broke this in some cases :-( However I'll be looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this for a game I worked on and I could not find a way to override it.  Even if you found a way, it would probably get you rejected from the app store, since there doesn't seem to be any public API for it.

Answer (score 0):

This be my answer. I'm not sure how you'd go about to actually execute the below as I guess implementions do things differently, but generally it sounds as there is a possibility, because after all these are the words of Apple regarding the multitasking gestures:

> "Developers are encouraged to evaluate any existing interactions in
>   their applications for potential sources of interference. In order to
>   properly interoperate with multitasking gestures, applications must
>   properly handle the following methods and notifications:
>   touchesCancelled:withEvent: (UIResponder) cancelTrackingWithEvent:
>   (UIControl) applicationDidBecomeActive: and
>   applicationWillResignActive: (application delegate)
>   UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and
>   UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification notifications These can be
>   enabled for development via Xcode so you can update your apps to
>   interoperate with these new gestures. Test them and give us your
>   feedback in the Apple Developer Forums."

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can because I have watched countless videos on how to override on iPhone/iPod but there are no ones for iPad must be so you can't cheat on games!

Comment: Please refrain from speculating.  Answers should be from personal programming experience or from authoritative sources such as documentation.